# AppleScript Syntax - getting a remote drive mounted

Tags: windows, applescript, mount

I have a remote drive (on an SBS 2011 server) mounted on my iMac BUT each time I reboot the iMac I have to relogin into the remote drive. How can I make this automatic?

I have come across some AppleScript approaches but none of them seem to work. E.g.

```
do shell script "mount_afp afp://username:password@192.168.100.2/Backups123 /Backups456"
```

Where username/password are valid for the remote server/folders, 192.168.100.2 is the IP of the Server and /Backups456 is the name of the mounted volume on the iMac.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you'd need to prefix that with `sudo` to mount a drive... `sudo mount_afp afp://....`

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding adding it to the list of login items in System Prefs?